# Concatenate Pandas column name to column value

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any efficient way to concatenate Pandas column name to its value. I will like to prefix all my DataFrame values with their column names.

My current method is very slow on a large dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data 

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO('''date value data
01/01/2019 30 data1
01/01/2019 40 data2
02/01/2019 20 data1
02/01/2019 10 data2'''), sep=' ')

# slow method 

dt = [df[c].apply(lambda x:f'{c}_{x}').values for c in df.columns]

dt = pd.DataFrame(dt, index=df.columns).T
```

The problem is that list compression and copying of data slows the transformation on a large dataset with lots of columns.

Is there are better way to prefix columns name to values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a way without loops:

```
pd.DataFrame([df.columns]*len(df),columns=df.columns)+"_"+df.astype(str)
```

---

```
              date     value        data
0  date_01/01/2019  value_30  data_data1
1  date_01/01/2019  value_40  data_data2
2  date_02/01/2019  value_20  data_data1
3  date_02/01/2019  value_10  data_data2
```

Timings (fastest to slowest):

```
m = pd.concat([df]*20000,ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
m.astype(str).radd(m.columns + '_')
#410 ms ± 39.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
m.astype(str).radd('_').radd([*m]) # courtesy @piR
#470 ms ± 76.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit      #piR solution
a = m.to_numpy().astype(str)
b = m.columns.to_numpy().astype(str)
pd.DataFrame(add(add(b, '_'), a), m.index, m.columns)
#710 ms ± 74.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit #anky_91 sol
pd.DataFrame([m.columns]*len(m),columns=m.columns)+"_"+m.astype(str)
#1.7 s ± 114 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit #OP sol
dt = [m[c].apply(lambda x:f' {c}_{x}').values for c in m.columns]
pd.DataFrame(dt, index=m.columns).T
#14.4 s ± 643 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to test this with a large dataset and return back with with results.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel added timings

Comment: You rock. This is perfect.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel try piR's solution, that runs faster for me

Comment: More concise way of doing similar thing.  `df.astype(str).radd('_').radd([*df])`

Comment: @piRSquared nice, thanks :) that runs even faster than the numpy sol :) you can add this to your sol

Comment: You should add all the timings.  Make this the best answer (-:

Comment: Sorry @anky_91 piRSquared method is blazing faster.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel He's referring to the comment I made.

Comment: Also, this is even faster `df.astype(str).radd(df.columns + '_')`

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel honestly I think you should accept piR answer because of the fastest solutions he suggested :)

Comment: Remarking as accepted answer as it has all the methods and timing. Thank you all @piRSquared.

Answer (score 2):

#### `numpy.core.defchararray.add`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

a = df.to_numpy().astype(str)
b = df.columns.to_numpy().astype(str)

dt = pd.DataFrame(add(add(b, '_'), a), df.index, df.columns)
dt

              date     value        data
0  date_01/01/2019  value_30  data_data1
1  date_01/01/2019  value_40  data_data2
2  date_02/01/2019  value_20  data_data1
3  date_02/01/2019  value_10  data_data2
```

---

This isn't as fast as the fastest answer but it's pretty zippy (see what I did there)

```
a = df.columns.tolist()
pd.DataFrame(
    [[f'{k}_{v}' for k, v in zip(a, t)]
     for t in zip(*map(df.get, a))],
    df.index, df.columns
)
```

Comment: this is even faster

Comment: This is a winner. This was blazing fast

Answer (score 0):

This solution:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({col: col + "_" + m[col].astype(str) for col in m.columns})
```

is as performant as the fastest solution above, and might be more readable, at least to some.